# Someone could tell me what kind of encrypt is it?

Tags: php, encryption, zend-guard

Well i got a php code encrypted, i thought it could be zend guard encrypt but it is not.

I post it in this link: http://pastebin.com/NxqmC4ku

I don't know if it possible to know.

Thanks.

Comment: I dont know which engine this this, but I have already decoded it 80% , it tries to find if file that is run on has domains such `motorsautoshow gcarro` and similar and there is a spanish comment Este script est� bloqueado para outros dom�nios.Contacte XXX At scriptsite. site

Comment: @BojanT could u tell me ?

Comment: It is just a PHP that is scrambled, var dump each segment of code command by command, and don't let eval command to execute , replace variables and array keys such as `O0O000O00` to something meaningful and after few minutes you have pretty good idea whats going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh dear, looks like your server got hacked.  The code will decode and execute itself when run, it's obfuscated to obscure its function.

It's self-decoding.  You can see the `eval()` in there.  If you change it to a `print()` then it will display the code that it's trying to execute.  This is nested several deeps, so each time you will need to change an `eval()` to a `print()` to see what's going on.  Be very careful when doing this, every time you see a construct like `$a($b)` then it's doing a function call, so you'll need to stop it from doing the function call and just print out `$a` and `$b`.